# WTSSendMessage on modern Windows Server

Tags: windows, messagebox, windows-server-2012-r2, wtsapi32

I'm writing a code for customized management of remote desktop sessions, similar to RD service manager from Windows Server. I'm using functions from wtsapi32.dll and winsta.dll to enumerate sessions, get session information, disconnect/logoff users and send messages to them.
I use [WTSSendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842(v=vs.85).aspx) to send message to user, and this is enough to emulate RD service manager functionality. I'd like to customize resulting message box with info/exclamation/error icon by specifying corresponding value in `Style` parameter. However, it works for previous generation of OS (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008R2) and client version of current generation (Windows 8) 
[image: WTSSendMessage with icon] 
but not for current generation of server (2012R2)
[image: WTSSendMessage without icon]
Is it possible to reinstate desired behavior in WinServer 2012R2, or use different API function? Or this API functionality was deprecated in 2012R2 (or simply lost in transition to Metro UI)?